# Enable systemd service file?

Tags: debian, systemd, debian-installer

I have created a `debian` package for one of my `autotool` project.I don't have any problem in `debian` creation and installation.The problem is that debian includes a `systemd` service file and I'm installing it to `/usr/lib/systemd/user/` but after installing the debian I'm not able to enable that service(unit file).

I tried adding

```
%: 
      dh $@ --with autoreconf --with-systemd
```

in `debian rules` file but it's not working.So is there any other way that I can enable the `systemd service` after installing my debian.

**Note:**
       No problem in the service file I can manually enable it after installing the debian using `systemctl` command.

Comment: Is the goal to get the service to start up after install? If your debian has a postinst maintainer script, and it isn't written properly, it can suddenly disables the auto-enable and start of services after install: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423069/postinst-maintainer-script-stops-systemd-unit-file-from-starting-automatically-o

Answer (score 2):

Is not very clean, but you can create a soft link to the service in the folder

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/
```

For example:

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/yourservice.service /usr/lib/systemd/user/yourservice.service
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, now I'm doing the same thing in the post installation script of my debian. But I want to avoid this. `dh` is providing the option to add it in the debian rules file(--with-systemd) but it's not working for me. :(

Comment: isn't it --with systemd the right syntax? not working for me neither :(

Comment: I think the example syntax is wrong.  it should be "ln - s <target> <link-name>".  ie. ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/user/yourservice.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/yourservice.service

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax is `--with systemd` , although `--with=systemd` also works.