# postinst maintainer script stops systemd unit file from starting automatically on install

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd

I'm creating a small Debian package to install systemd unit files, specifically `*.service` files.

My package looks like:

```
myservice
      | 
      |--debian
            |- comapat
            |- preinst
            |- postinst
            |- rules
            |- myservice.service
```

When I install my package, the systemd services are automatically disabled and they do not start up.

Right after install, `systemctl status myservice` shows

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# systemctl status myservice
  ● myservice.service - My Service - echos output and says when it started
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
```

However, when I install my package **without a `postinst` script**, the systemd services are automatically enabled and they do start up after install.

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~# systemctl status myservice
● myservice.service - MyService - echos output and says when it started
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-02-09 15:06:36 UTC; 10s ago
Main PID: 5024 (sh)
Tasks: 2
Memory: 172.0K
  CPU: 1ms
CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service
       ├─5024 /bin/sh -c echo 'myservice.service started' && echo $(date +%s) && sleep infinity
       └─5026 sleep infinity
```

I'm confused because my postinst is "small and dumb":

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# POSTINST script for myservice
set -e

echo "\033[36m HI I'M A POSTINST SCRIPT `date +"%s"` \033[39m"
```

**Why does the presence of a postinst overwrite the "automatic enabling and starting" of a systemd service?** 
What part of debhelper deals with this and what am I missing? 
Or **what should I add to my `postinst` maintainer script to get my services up and running on install?**

---

NOTES: My environment is a small vagrant box with a virtualbox provider. I am using the [ubuntu-xenial64 Vagrant box](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64). Not sure if this environment affects this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `debhelper` placeholder to your `postinst`:

```
#DEBHELPER#
```

So your `postinst` should look like

```
#!/bin/sh
# POSTINST script for intera
set -e

echo "\033[36m HI I'M A POSTINST SCRIPT `date +"%s"` \033[39m"

#DEBHELPER#

exit 0
```

If you don’t include that, `debhelper` won’t add its auto-generated `postinst` snippets to your maintainer script. When you don’t have a `postinst` at all, it just generates the entire script; but if you have your own version, it only changes the placeholder.

Comment: Thanks!  This solved my issue. It looks like I was "gotten" by the devil in the details of debhelper.